# WP7 - Set background image on all pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

My goal is to set a background picture for each page. 
Consider this structure...

```
/Images/AppBackground.jpg
/App.xaml
/MainPage.xaml
/Page2.xaml
```

My first try was setting it on the rootframe as suggested elsewhere on this site... ;)

**App.xaml.cs**

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush
{
    ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/AppBackground.jpg", UriKind.Relative)),
    Opacity = 0.5d
};
this.RootFrame.Background = brush;
```

This will give me an error: 
`A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

I tried with and without the starting `/`, tried `UriKind.Absolute`, And without a `UriType` parameter, all will give me the same error. The Image `AppBackground.jpg` has Build Action `Content`.

Below code will work just fine.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/AppBackground.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    ...
```

But that's not what I want, I don't want to set it for each page...

Anyone any idea what I'm screwing up? ;)

Comment: It should work if you use UriKind.Relative, set the build action to content, and remove the / : `ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/AppBackground.jpg", UriKind.Relative))`

Comment: I tried that already, and tried it again, same error... :(

I've put this code at the end of the `public App()` constructor. Might that be the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crap. Wrong place; I was to early. In the constructor, it will simple overwrite the `Background` setting...

If I execute it at a later point, it'll work just fine... :)

```
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush
    {
        ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/AppBackground.jpg", UriKind.Relative)),
        Opacity = 0.5d
    };
    this.RootFrame.Background = brush;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the problem with setting the background for each page separately in XAML? If the background should be dynamic, you could implement a state flag, that will tell the application what state it is in, therefore knowing what wallpaper to load.

Couple this with the background bound to a converter (convert state to `ImageBrush`) and you've got yourself the solution.

Comment: Because if I want to change it or something (i.e. the opacity) I have to do that in every page. I would like to do it in just one place. Yes, in this example there are just two pages, but that's not in the 'real' situation.

Comment: From a user experience standpoint, I would avoid having the same background everywhere, this - state check. But that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but in this case I need this... Also, with the Transition effects from the toolkit, if the background is on the page, the background moves with the effect. If it's on the frame, it stays nicely in place... :) Thanks anyhow for your input, appreciate it!